# Displaying only 5 from table

Tags: php, limit

I'm trying to make it where you can see you friends latest activity, but only 5 can be shown at a time.  Of the 5, you can have one person more than once if your the time you have is more than any other friend.  Like it would say "friend levelled up skillName date" and then display the five most recent ones.  My code is something like this:

```
function recentActivityF($user){
include "mysql.ws";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT u.* FROM friends uf inner join users u on uf.friend = u.username WHERE uf.user = '$user' ORDER BY u.username") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $friends = $row['username'];    
            //$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recentactivity WHERE user LIKE '".$friends."' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT u.* FROM recentactivity uf inner join friends u on uf.user = u.friend WHERE uf.user LIKE '".$friends."' ORDER BY uf.time DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
            $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE playerName LIKE '".$friends."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)){
         while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
        $date = $row2['time'];
        $skillRow = $row2['skill']+1;
        $skill = findType($skillRow)."xp";
        $skillName = findType($skillRow);
                echo'Friend: '.$friends.' Levelled Up '.$skillName.' Date: '.$date.'';
              }
            }
         }
       }
```

The result should be:

```
1.)Friend: mark Levelled Up Attack date: 28-Aug-2012 09:48
2.)Friend: matt Levelled Up Strength date: 28-Aug-2012 09:47
3.)Friend: kevin Levelled Up Attack date: 28-Aug-2012 09:46
4.)Friend: mark Levelled Up Strength date: 28-Aug-2012 09:45
5.)Friend: april Levelled Up Magic date: 28-Aug-2012 09:44
```

My result is:

```
1.)Friend: mark Levelled Up Attack date: 28-Aug-2012 09:48
2.)Friend: mark Levelled Up Strength date: 28-Aug-2012 09:45
3.)Friend: matt Levelled Up Strength date: 28-Aug-2012 09:47
4.)Friend: kevin Levelled Up Attack date: 28-Aug-2012 09:46
5.)Friend: april Levelled Up Magic date: 28-Aug-2012 09:44
6.)Friend: april Levelled Up Strength date: 28-Aug-2012 09:45
```

SQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `user` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `friend` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `friends` (`user`, `friend`) VALUES
('Cls Prod', 'pro skiller'),
('Cls Prod', 'polo303'),
('Cls Prod', 'pjtips123'),
('Cls Prod', 'tommy0581'),
('Cls Prod', 'sageofmali');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rights` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `friends` text,
  `donator` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `rights`, `online`, `friends`, `donator`, `time`) VALUES
('Cls Prod', 'password', '0', 0, NULL, NULL, 0);

CREATE TABLE `recentactivity` (
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `skill` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `killed` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `recentactivity` (`user`, `skill`, `time`, `killed`) VALUES
('Cls Prod', 2, '27-Aug-2012 16:06:40', '');
```

So the commented $query2 shows 1 from each friend, but will show more than 5, I want to limit it to only 5 of the most recent friends activity to be shown.  Any help?

Comment: re-ask the question, this time just with a SQl and show the expected result.

Comment: Note: don't use LIKE when it is not necessary (no wildcards, etc) and you are simply looking for equality

Comment: Think I found what you needed in my last edit--including specific columns. Thanks for the work-out! :P

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that there is absolutely no research done prior to asking questions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you're doing skill-to-skillName translations yourself, so this should be enough:

```
SELECT f.user AS username, a.time, a.skill
FROM
  friends f
  JOIN recentactivity a ON(a.user = f.user)
WHERE
 f.friend = $username
GROUP BY a.user -- only one event per friend
ORDER BY a.time DESC
LIMIT 5
```

See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66f53/6

---

Edit: this is all you need to do:

```
function recentActivityF($user){
  include "mysql.ws";
  $query = <<<EOD
SELECT f.user AS username, a.time, a.skill
FROM
  friends f
  JOIN recentactivity a ON(a.user = f.user)
WHERE
 f.friend = $user
GROUP BY a.user -- only one event per friend
ORDER BY a.time DESC
LIMIT 5
EOD;

  mysql_query($query);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $friend_name = $row['username'];
    $date = $row['time'];
    $skillRow = $row['skill']+1;
    $skillName = findType($skillRow);
    echo'Friend: '.$friend_name.' Levelled Up '.$skillName.' Date: '.$date.'';
  }
```

P.S. Standard Stack-Overflow disclaimer: The mysql extension is deprecated, please use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: No problem. Always fun. Give http://sqlfiddle.com a look next time you have a database-related question, K? :)

Comment: Actually, now it shows the same 5 for every user.

Comment: With GROUP BY: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/651d5/1/0 ... without GROUP BY: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/651d5/2

Comment: Hmm, username seems to be missing somewhere that's how I get the friend name from the username column.

Comment: Yeah, I dropped the JOIN to users and am now referencing the `f.user` column. You can add an alias to make it *look like* username, like here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a423/2/0

Comment: Hmm Something seems to be messed up;  It shows the right user and stuff but will have different information for some people. Maybe you can spot out the problem: http://codepaste.net/q8y864

Comment: It doesn't get the friends most recent time for each person.

Comment: Removing the group by fixed it, what did the group by do?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is outside the scope of the comments thread. Start here:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

### Use a [sql limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id820542).

The basic usage is this:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5
```

If you want to return records 6-10:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5,5
```

Give me a moment to look through your code to give a good example. It's not obvious in your code where you need to use it.

---

After looking through your code a bit, it seems you don't need the first query. You should be able to do:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM recentactivity uf
INNER JOIN friends u ON uf.user = u.friend
WHERE u.user = $user
ORDER BY uf.time DESC
LIMIT 5
```

You may have to select more fields to get all of the information you need, but that should get you all the records on `recentactivity` for a given user, sorted by latest and limited to the top 5.

Comment: No, I think he needs to do a JOIN or two.

Comment: Yeah I think I need to join something, but not sure of the right way to do it.